# wxrichtextctrl font dialog box

Tags: wxpython

I am developing a small app with wxrichtextctrl. My font function is behaving unexpectedly. The following is the font function.

```
    def OnFont(self,event):
      if not self.display.HasSelection():
          return
      r = self.display.GetSelectionRange()
      fontData = wx.FontData()
      fontData.EnableEffects(False)
      attr = wx.richtext.RichTextAttr()
      attr.SetFlags(wx.TEXT_ATTR_FONT)
      dlg = wx.FontDialog(self, fontData)
      if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        fontData = dlg.GetFontData()
        font = fontData.GetChosenFont()
        color=fontData.GetChosenColor()
        if font:
            attr.SetFlags(wx.TEXT_ATTR_FONT)
            attr.SetFont(font)
            self.display.SetStyle(r, attr)
      dlg.Destroy()
```

The problem with this is that if the selected text is underlined and some font is set, the underline is removed. Is there any way for the dialog to only modify the selections present font rather than changing the text weight, underline, italics. Or is this possible with richtextformatting dialog. Or is it possible to modify the fontdialog to show only the select font and size options and modify the selected text. can someone point to a good sample documentation.

UPDATED:
I am able to set a predefined font for the dialog, but the problem is getting the font value of the selected text. What I am trying is to get the style of the first character in the selection, and set it to the font dialog, including underline, font, bold,italic and size. 
Below is code I mam trying to do.

```
    attr = wx.richtext.RichTextAttr()
    attr.SetFlags(wx.TEXT_ATTR_FONT)
    fontofselection=self.richtextctrl.GetStyle(1,attr)#this works without errors 
    fontData.SetInitialFont(fontofselection)#this generates above mentioned error. probably because getstyle is not getting font object type. Is there another method to get font of a character at particular position.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can make use of the default FontDialog to disable/enable certain fields. It comes as is. However, you can choose to preset it to a certain value and/or ignore certain values.

To do that you can pass the `data` argument to the [dialog constructor](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.FontDialog-class.html#__init__). You have to construct the FontData object yourself and pass that to the dialog. This piece of sample code is taken from the [Mouse vs. Python](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/26/the-dialogs-of-wxpython-part-1-of-2/) blog:

```
data = wx.FontData()
data.EnableEffects(True)
data.SetColour(self.curClr)         # set colour
data.SetInitialFont(self.curFont)

dlg = wx.FontDialog(self, data)
```

Check the article for a more complete example. Also look at the docs for the [FontData](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.FontData-class.html) object to know how to construct it and manipulate it.

Alternatively, you can use the less user-friendly dialog (IMO) [FontEnumerator](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.FontEnumerator-class.html). Also on that same blog is another [great example](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/04/28/wxpython-learning-to-use-fonts/). You can also get a list of all the fonts you need and/or other parameters and make you own `Dialog`.

**Update**

To get the correct data from the text at a specific position, you need to use [`GetStyle`](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl-class.html#GetStyle) or `GetStyleForRange`, but you are using it wrong. If you read the docs, you would have noticed that these return `True` for success or `False` for failure, and that you should use the `attr` to get the result. For example:

```
attr = wx.richtext.RichTextAttr()
attr.SetFlags(wx.TEXT_ATTR_FONT)
success=self.richtextctrl.GetStyle(1,attr)
fontData.SetInitialFont(attr.GetFont()) # And extract any other information from there
```

Note that this is not tested but should work as expected.

Please check the [docs](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.richtext.TextAttrEx-class.html) for the `RichTextAttr` to see what you can extract from there. I think the underline/bold/italic is all in the Font object: check `GetUnderlined`, `GetWeight` and `GetStyle` (with their respective setters.

Always check the docs, you would have found your answers in less than an hour :)

Comment: I need little more help. I tried getting font of a text at position say 1 using font=self.display.GetStyle(1,attr) where attr and display are defined in above in my question. But when I set the font i saved in getstyle, using data.setinitialfont(font), it says expected argument of type wxfontconstant. My problem is I need to set the font of selection to the font dialog including underline and color

Comment: in the above on it said expected argument two of type wxfontconstant. Is there a better way of getting font including underline of selection and in the above solution how do I tick the underline in the font dialog.

Comment: There is a method called [wx.Font.SetUnderlined](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Font-class.html#SetUnderlined). Usually, if you are getting it from the control, it should already be set I guess. Also, I can't find any documentation about that `wxFontConstant`. Can you edit your question with your new code? Just a simple example so I can see exactly what you are getting..

Comment: @MYNE me too! Check the answer.